# What is the best way to combine akka-http flow in a scala-stream flow

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http

I have an use case where after **n** flows of Akka-stream, I have to take the result of one of them and made a request to a HTTP REST API.

The last akka-stream flow type, before the HTTP request is a string:

```
val stream1:Flow[T,String,NotUsed] = Flow[T].map(_.toString)
```

Now, HTTP request should be specified, I thought about something like:

```
val stream2: Flow[String,Future[HttpRespone],NotUsed] = Flow[String].map(param => Http.singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri=s"host.com/$param")))
```

and then combine it:

```
val stream3 = stream1 via stream2
```

Is it the best way to do it? Which ways you guys would actually recommend and why? A couple of best praxis examples in the scope of this use case would be great!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you really want a `Flow[String, Future[HttpResponse, NotUsed]]` and not a `Flow[String, HttpResponse, NotUsed]` ?

Comment: Hey Ruediger, Future[String] is actually what is returned by Http.singleRequest(...), anyway that's not the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation would create a new connection to `"host.com"` for each new param.  This is unnecessary and prevents akka from making certain optimizations.  Under the hood akka actually keeps a connection pool around to reuse open connections but I think it is better to specify your intentions in the code and not rely on the underlying implementation.

You can make a single connection as described in the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/scala/http/client-side/connection-level.html#connection-level-api):

```
val connectionFlow: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, _] = 
  Http().outgoingConnection("host.com")
```

To utilize this connection Flow you'll need to convert your String paths to `HttpRequest` objects:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.Uri
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.Uri.Path

def pathToRequest(path : String) = HttpRequest(uri=Uri.Empty.withPath(Path(path)))

val reqFlow = Flow[String] map pathToRequest
```

And, finally, glue all the flows together:

```
val stream3 = stream1 via reqFlow via connectionFlow
```

This is the most common pattern for continuously querying the same server with different request objects.

Comment: Hey Ramon! Thank you for your time to answer my question. According to the documentation of Http.singleRequest(...).. there is:    * Fires a single [[HttpRequest]] across the (cached) host connection pool for the request's... So it use a cached connection pool under the hood.

Comment: I agree there is an underlying cache, as stated in my answer.  But why rely on the settings/logic of the akka cache when you can establish the connection yourself and re-use the same connection?

Comment: According to the [akka-documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/scala/http/client-side/connection-level.html#Opening_HTTP_Connections):  `Note that no connection is attempted until the returned flow is actually materialized! If the flow is materialized several times then several independent connections will be opened (one per materialization). If the connection attempt fails, for whatever reason, the materialized flow will be immediately terminated with a respective exception.` That means, that your solution would produce N connections for N Materialized flows.

Comment: Correct.  But why materialize N Flows???  You materialize 1 Flow and use it over-and-over with different `HttpRequest` objects...

Comment: And how would you deal with the fact, that `Http()` requires an `ActorSystem` to be constructed (I suppose that when `Http` is constructed, it automatically manages materialization internally)? It doesn't make much sense if I just try to include `Http` as a flow in my bigger stream and materialize the whole stream later on.